# drawables showing in block form

Tags: android, android-studio, drawable

A few of my *pngs* and *jpegs* files from the *drawables* resources folder have been showing up as single-colored "blocks" that represent the general area the png/jpg should take up.
I've attached images of what are supposed to be a download button in a `recyclerview`, and a Chinese and British flag. The material icon "ic_file_download..." is the one that is turning into a white blob.

The flags "english.png" and "chinese.jpg" are the ones turning into colored blobs, although they are clearly not as I can see when I open the file in android studio.
    Anybody know what's going on here?

My Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:style="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/busRouteTextStyle"
        android:id="@+id/bus_route"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/downloaded_count"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="/"
        android:id="@+id/slashie"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:id="@+id/firebase_count"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_file_download_white_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/download_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Android Studio**
[image: Android Studio]

**Download Icon as seen on phone**
[image: Download Icon as seen on phone]

**Flags as seen on phone**
[image: Flags as seen on phone]

Comment: Can you post the code of your row layout for the recyclerview?

Comment: Just edited! @Ryan

Comment: Seems more like they're somehow cropped instead of scaled...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is your image is way larger than your ImageButton and you are not telling Android to do any scaling on your image. Try changing your ImageButton xml to this:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_file_download_white_24dp"
    android:id="@+id/download_button"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```